# Join in mongodb using yii2

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

Join in mongodb using yii2

```
Suppose i have two table
1. post(id, title, body, userid)
2. user(id, name, date)
```

How can we join these two table based on userid(id of user table is userid in post table)?

Comment: Isn't there a case where `join` in Yii 2 is independent from the underlying engine? It should be like in any other db case.

Comment: Since this question lacks research: it's in the activerecord

Comment: i just want to implement some functionality in mongoDB and Yii2 similar like join in mysql and Yii2

Comment: you can use lookup aggregation method in mongodb
there is aggregation is same as join

Answer (score -1):

1. post(id, title, body, user:{'id','name'})
2. user(id, name, date)